# Split string at a specific number that is also contained in a larger number in the same string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the string: `'This line is 14 1400'`

I would like to split it keeping everything to the right of `14`.

I have tried:

```
split2 = re.split('14', string)[2]
```

This returns: `00`

I would like it to return `1400`

How would I modify this to get this output?  I've experimented with expression operations to only consider `14` but can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: `re.split(r'\b14\b', string)`?

Comment: But is there a reason why a simple `string.split()[-1]` will not work?

Answer (score 2):

To split only on `14` and not on `1400`, use the *word boundary* metacharacter `\b`.

Make sure to use a raw string to avoid having to escape the `\`.

```
>>> split2 = re.split(r'\b14\b', string)
>>> split2
['This line is ', ' 1400']
>>> split2[1]
' 1400'
```

Alternatively, to also get rid of the leading space in `' 1400'`, do not split only on `14` but also on any spaces surrounding it:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s*\b14\b\s*', s)
['This line is', '1400']
```

Comment: Alternatively, wrap the pattern in a group - `r'(\b14\b)'` - so it also exists in the result list